# Allow method to accept an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Making a DSL, and I'm just wondering if there's a way to make a method accept an array without placing the array in square brackets.

For example, this works:

```
def foo args=[]
    args.each { |arg| puts arg }
end
foo ['baz','boo','bing'] #=> 'baz','boo','bing'
```

But I'd like to be able to hand foo its arguments without the square brackets:

```
foo 'baz','boo','bing' #=> 'baz','boo','bing'
```

Not a game changer, just wondering if it can be done :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! It's call the "splat" operator. It will take whatever is left over in stuff it in an array.

```
def foo(*args)
  args.each { |arg| puts arg }
end

> foo 'baz','boo','bing' 
baz
boo
bing
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this with the splat operator

```
def foo *args
   args.each { |arg| puts arg }
end
foo 'baz','boo','bing' #=> 'baz','boo','bing'
```